# Angular 2's equivalent to window.location.href?

Tags: angular, angular-new-router

How can one navigate to a different URL within Angular 2? I know that we can use JavaScript's

> window.location.href = '...';

But that seems wrong and would cause a page refresh. I am pretty sure that there should be functionality in Angular 2 that will allow you to move between URLs without refreshing the page. I just can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can use **Router** and its **navigate** function to change current state, and also pass the parameters, if neccessary:

```
import {Component, ...} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Router, ...} from 'angular2/router';
import {HomeCmp} from '../home/home';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  // params of your component here
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: HomeCmp, as: 'MyHome' },
  // your other states here
])

export class AppCmp {
  router: Router;
  constructor(router: Router) {
    this.router = router;
  }
  navigateToHome() {
    // for example, that's how we can navigate to our home route
    this.router.navigate(['./MyHome', {param: 3}]);
  }
}
```

Here is the link to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router).

And here is a [link](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) to seed project with a great example of using Router.

Comment: Hey Punov, Thanks a million for the help and the link! ;)

Comment: Oh, I made a little mistake, fixed.

Comment: This only works for navigating within the app itself.  You can't use this to route to a completely external URL like `http://www.cnn.com` for example.

Comment: @MichaelOryl is case of the need is to navigate to an external url, you can simply use `window.location.href='http://www.cnn.com'`. Otherwise just follow the answer.

Comment: Thats just horribly untestable @MacKentoch

Comment: official documentation link broken

Comment: `window.location.href = ...` (for non-angular URLs) equivalent for angular is `location.go()` function: https://angular.io/api/common/Location#go

Comment: please note that `location.go()` does not redirect the page, only changes is history API state. If you need to redirect, you can `inject` document (`import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';`) into your constructor (`@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document`) and use `this.document.location.href = ...`